# Select HTML content inside a <div> and appendTo

Tags: jquery, html, appendto

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<div id="aa">
 <select><option>1</option></select>
 <select><option>a</option></select>
</div>

<div id="bb"></div>

$('#aa').html(appendTo('#bb'));
```

How can I move the two select menus inside `#aa` to `#bb`?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to *move* them, and not copy them, do this:

```
$('#aa').children().appendTo('#bb');
```

If you *do* want to copy them, you can do this:

```
$('#aa').children().clone(true).appendTo('#bb');
```

Both of these prevent you from needlessly destroying DOM elements, and they retain any event handlers on the elements.

---

**EDIT:** I was going the wrong direction. I had the children of `bb` appended to `aa`. Fixed.

Comment: would the .children().appendTo() call remove it from #bb? I didn't know that (:

Comment: @Jim: Yes, it will actually relocate the elements from their current location to the destination.

Answer (score 1):

Move, or copy?

You could use this to copy:

`$('#bb').html($('#aa').html());`

And if you're clearing the `#aa` just do:

`$('#aa').html('');`

http://jsfiddle.net/VhuG7/

Comment: Also $('#aa').empty() would work as well for clearing it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#aa>select').appendTo('#bb);
```

Moves all 'select' elements from aa to bb

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#bb').html($('#aa').html());
```

this should work